# Prioritisation of contact autocompletion in Evolution?

Tags: email, evolution

I have Evolution (3.36.5-0ubuntu1, running on on Ubuntu 20.04) set up for autocompletion when entering email addresses from my Contacts lists. I configured Evolution to use several contacts lists and a global address list. What I'd now like to do is to prioritise autocomplete suggestions between these lists, e.g. to first suggest contacts from my personal address book before contacts from the global address list. Is there a way to set this up?

Comment: Hello. I see you have an Evolution question. As this is an Ubuntu OS support site I suggest an Evolution support site would be a better place for this question.

Comment: Clarified, this is Evolution running on Ubuntu. Evolution is a tag on AskUbuntu, and I figure the Ubuntu community might have insights here.

Comment: Usually yes, and it's surely not off-topic, but as this is a very specific question to a software I guess you might find better answers elsewhere (e.g. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution)